# Как обратиться к полям и методам объектов, которые находятся в векторе?

Tags: c++, классы, vector, stl

Вот, например, у меня есть такой класс:

```
class students
{
public:
    string name;
    int score;
    int age;
    students(string name, int score, int age)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->score = score;
        this->age = age;
    }
};
```

И вот такой вектор:

```
vector<students> vc =
    {
        students("Ваня", 124, 22),
        students("Саша", 140, 24),
        students("Миша", 127, 19),
        students("Вася", 131, 22),
        students("Максим", 119, 19),
        students("Сережа", 141, 25),
        students("Леша", 116, 18),
        students("Олег", 121, 18)
    };
```

Вопрос: можно ли как-то по индексу ячейки вектора (или еще по чему-то) обратиться к полям и методам объекта, который находится в этой ячейке? Например, я хочу установить объекту, который находится в 3 ячейке, другое значение в поле score, но именно через точку, а не через конструктор. Как я могу и могу ли вообще это сделать?

Comment: Я бы сначала  попробовал...

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, неработающий код и сообщение об ошибке. Мы его исправим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запросто:

```
vc[2].score = new_value;
```

Конечно, пока поля объявлены как `public`.

Можно только предложение? А именно - переписать конструктор без лишних копирований:

```
students(const string& name, int score, int age):name(name),score(score),age(age){}
```

И - мелочь, конечно - но при беглом взгляде кажется, что `students` - *студенты* - это и есть вектор. А один - все-таки `student`. А чтоб отличать тип от объекта - я бы воспользовался стандартным соглашением, что имя пользовательского типа начинается с прописной буквы - `Student`...